# Python Console List printed in console without a print command

Tags: python

I am getting a weird behavior with the code below. More precisely, I am seeing a behavior in the console that I am not asking the code to do.

```
text_list = ["text1", 
             "text2", 
             "text3"]

def loop_categories(lang):
    
    ###This is a function to loop through categories & categories description by chunk of 5 
    ###Every chunk is added with category "Else" as a back up for future matching
    
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.read_csv("category_list.csv", sep = ";")
    df = df[df['lang'] == lang]
    
    #Find the "Else" row (if not found, add it)
    else_row = df[df['Category'] == 'Else'].iloc[0]
    else_string = else_row['Category']
    else_description = f"{else_row['Category']}: {else_row['Description']}"  
    
    #If the category size is below 5, then keep adding them 
    i = 0
    while i < len(df):
        subset = df[i:i+5]
        
        # If the subset is empty, break the loop
        if subset.empty:
            break

        # If "Else" is not in the subset, add it
        if 'Else' not in subset['Category'].values:
            theme_string = ', '.join(subset['Category'].values.tolist() + [else_string])
            theme_descriptions = ', '.join([f"{row['Category']}: {row['Description']}" for idx, row in subset.iterrows()] + [else_description])
        else:
            theme_string = ', '.join(subset['Category'].values.tolist())
            theme_descriptions = ', '.join([f"{row['Category']}: {row['Description']}" for idx, row in subset.iterrows()])
        
        #Return the last 5 categories & corresponding description including the "Else" one
        yield theme_string, theme_descriptions
        i += 5
        if i >= len(df):
            break




def categorization_llm (lang):
    
    from langchain.llms import OpenAI
    from module_categorization import loop_categories
    from module_smalltools import clean_string, category_stripper
    
    def llm_query (prompt):  #To query the LLM model with the prompt
        
        llm = OpenAI(model_name="text-davinci-003",openai_api_key="xxxxx")
        response = llm(prompt)

        return response
    
    
    category_list2 = []
    for texts in text_list:

        category_list = [] #Set a list where all categories attributed will be stored temporarily
        
        ###Go through all chunks of categories & assess to which the piece of text belong
        
        for theme_string, theme_descriptions in loop_categories(lang): #Loop through chunks of 5 categories
            prompt_categorization = f'''
                myprompt
                '''
            
            response = llm_query (prompt_categorization)  #Get the category for each piece of text x 5 cat. chunk 
            response = clean_string(response) #Clean the output from potential unusual formating
            response = category_stripper(response)

            category_list.append(response)
            
        category_list2.append(list(set(category_list)))
                    
    return category_list2    
        

x = categorization_llm ("en")
print("")
```

For some reason, the `category_list2` gets printed in my console though I do not want to display it. I have never seen this behavior before. What could be causing such weird situation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an interactive Python console? An interactive Python console prints the returned values regardless of whether you use the print() function. Try running the file from the command line using "python script.py"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).